# How to validate bootstrap multiselect dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am trying to validate Bootstrap multiselect dropdown using the code given below, the form is getting validated but i did'nt get the proper output, the 
validation message is above the selectbox and the message gets multiplied when 
clicking on the submit button and after selecting option the message did'nt gets removed. Please help to solve my problem.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $.validator.addMethod("needsSelection", function (value, element) {
            var count = $(element).find('option:selected').length;
            return count > 0;
          });

        $.validator.messages.needsSelection = 'Select Atleast One College'; 

          $("#User").validate({
                  rules: {    
                    'college[]': {
                    needsSelection: true
                    }
                  },
              }
          });

 $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    var isvalidate=$("#User").valid();
    if(isvalidate=="true")
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $("#User").submit();
    }
 });

});

    <form id="User" name="User" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index">   
        <select data-placeholder="Choose College Name" name="college[]" class="chosen-select" id="college" multiple tabindex="4">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">abc</option>
                    <option value="2">abc1</option>
        </select>
    <a id="submit">Submit</a>
    </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but may provide a solution to your problem.

First, change the anchor tag to a button -- because anchor tags have built-in navigation behaviour that you must counter (`event.preventDefault()`) and therefore add needless complexity. How about a button (input or button tags) or a div tag, or a p?)

Next, a simpler structure to evaluating your form:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6fps7a99/)</kbd>

**HTML:** (just changed your anchor submit button to:

```
<input id="dosubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Note: do not use "submit" as the id for a submit button, as that is a reserved keyword

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('#User').submit(function(e){
    var col = $('#college').val();
    if ( col==null || col=='' || col=='Please choose one:' ){
        $('#college').css('background','yellow').focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        $('#college').css('background','transparent');
        alert('Form submitted');
        //continue to submit the form - but not now
        return false;
    }
});
```

Please consider [this verification script](http://jsfiddle.net/W4g4e/7/) for your project.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question but I will advise you and encourage you to use a server-side validation together.

Your data should be validate and as needed sanitzed on the php file that receives the ajax call.

If something is going wrong there, the response will always be passed back to your form giving your users the needed feedback.

You can find many examples on the internet of how to do this.

See here an example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

So to recap: Dont't do client-side validation!!